# how do I start and stop GPS tracking in an Android application?

Tags: android, gps

In my Android application when I press the stop button the GPS stops tracking the user location.

Specifically I defined methods like removeupdates in that button event.

But now I want to start the GPS tracking again after it has been stopped.

Can you tell me what I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register LocationListener one more time.

Comment: sorry I can't get the question. You have listener object. You just should ask your locationManager to requestLocationUpdates using that object when you need receive location changes and removeUpdates when you don't